# angular 2 localization change language

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to build a change lang buttons but not sure where to start, what I plan on doing is to have buttons for each supported langs and call out vars of these langs.

found this https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/i18n/

Idea is to change 'aa-dj' dynamically depending on the button you click and pass it to the script src {{ }}.
https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/i18n/angular-locale_aa-dj.js

```html
in index.html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/i18n/angular-locale{{}}.js"></script>
```

Comment: anyone? is there a way to do <script [src]="...{{}}.js">? as I've been trying and it doesn't seems to work aha. How do I escape {{}} from the ""

Comment: Okay I think I can't do in the index.html as I don't have access to the component or somthing.